# Diffing Sql Schema

Tags: sql, diff

I need to move some changes from database a to database b, and some from b to a. Every comparison tool I've used requires you to pick a direction first and if you want to go the other direction, well then you get to wait for it to completely re-compare all over again.

Also the tools I've used don't allow you to make changes on the fly. If I see something I need to update, I've got to go update it using SSMS and then come back to the tool and re-compare all over again.

What I really want is a tool that works just like a text diffing application (BeyondCompare, WinMerge, etc.).

I've thought about trying to write my own app to do this so many times but it's a big undertaking so I always say "nah, it's not worth it". Well I've finally decided to give it a shot but I just want a final word on 2 issues:

1) Have I overlooked some amazing product that already does this? I've searched but haven't found anything. Would hate to waste a lot of time if someone has already done it though.

2) What Diffing api would be best suited for this type of application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tool for doing this action is from redgate called sql compare.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare

Comment: Oh gees. I feel dumb for not checking up on this product to see if it did what i wanted. I haven't used it in a really, really long time and just didn't even think to look if they'd added the features Thanks.